# Are financial aid checks taxable and as a student how do I pay taxes on these checks?

Tags: taxes, irs, student

I'm going to trade school and excelling grade-wise.  Every so often I've been getting *financial-aid* checks from the community college.

This is what was left after the most basic things were paid by finacial-aid. Such as classes, lab-fees, and etc.

I've been keeping records of what I cashed and how much. My bank also has copies of these cashed checks.

Edit: The money is in my checkings account.

### Question

How do I go about reporting this income?

What particularly IRS forms would I need?

Comment: I've been using the checkings money to pay for tools for my trade class every so often.

Comment: Tools ARE a necessity. Just like books are in regular academic classes.

Comment: What kind of financial aid is it? Pell grants, scholarships, etc.?

Comment: @Nosjack I believe its a pell grant. FAFSA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pell grants [are non-taxable](https://www.hrblock.com/tax-center/income/other-income/is-federal-student-aid-taxable/) as long as they are used for "qualified tuition and other education expenses". Classes, lab fees, and books are all considered qualified. Room and board and any amounts over the total qualified expenses are not qualified, and therefore taxable.

In short, the only amount of the grant that is taxable is whatever is used to pay for room and board or sent directly to you (and also not later used for a qualified expense).

All of this is reported in [IRS Form 1098-T](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1098et.pdf) which is sent to you sometime in January or early February. Box 1 includes the total amount paid for qualified expenses for the year. Box 5 will include the total amount of scholarships and grants. In your case, Box 5 will be more than Box 1, and the difference is the taxable amount.

Note that if you have qualified expenses that you pay out of pocket and not through your school (e.g., rent books on Amazon) it will not be included on your 1098-T. You will have to add those expenses in yourself when you file, and save the receipts.

See also this [Turbo Tax thread](https://ttlc.intuit.com/community/college-education/discussion/is-the-entire-box-5-1098-t-taxable/00/756462) for additional explanation.

Comment: Okay, to repeat what you said. (To make sure I understand) All those checks sent to me are taxable. An IRS Form 1098-T will be sent to my address? Right now its early February.

Comment: @TravisWells Correct, it is all taxable, unless you used the money later for a qualified expense in the same year (e.g., books). Keep in mind that your school may only send the 1098-T to you electronically through some account portal. Contact the financial aid office if you don't receive it by mid-February. You should also verify that the amount shown in Box 1 of the form is correct. Note that books purchased out-of-pocket (with your own credit card on Amazon for example), would not be reported on the 1098-T.

Comment: If they send checks in the mail; how do they get their tax-money? Do they take debit?  (I know its a silly question)

Comment: @TravisWells Not silly at all! Your federal tax obligation is tallied up when you file your tax return with the IRS. If you owe, you send a check or provide your bank info to the IRS for them to withdrawal. If you overpaid and are due a refund, you can request a check be sent to your or direct-deposit into your account. The school does not usually withhold taxes for you.

Comment: @TravisWells+ in addition to paying _while filing_ (which Nosjack described and is usually easiest) there are other payment options [per the instructions for 1040 line 23, which is the amount you need to pay](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi#idm139798481261664) including via debit or credit card -- but those charge a 'convenience fee' because by law IRS, unlike a private merchant, can't allow the card network to keep the interchange fee on a transaction, so the other methods are usually less costly.

Answer (score 0):

Some kinds of financial aid (like grants and scholarships that go towards living and other expenses of being in college) may be considered as “taxable income” by the IRS and must be declared on tax returns.

“Financial aid and grants are generally not considered taxable income, provided the money is spent for tuition, fees, books and other supplies for classes,” he said. ... While work-study is a type of financial aid, it is still money earned. That means it has to be reported to the IRS.

https://www.simpletuition.com/financial-aid/taxes/

Comment: Who are you quoting?  Please provide a link.

Comment: @RonJohn Considering that work-study is basically employment. That's a guaranteed taxable income. But, since I'm dealing with Uncle Sam (who scares me) I want to make sure that I understand 100%..

Comment: @TravisWells that's why Larry needed to provide a link.

Comment: The quote *“Financial aid and grants are generally not considered taxable income, provided the money is spent for tuition, fees, books and other supplies for classes,” he said* is nowhere in the link https://www.simpletuition.com/financial-aid/taxes/.